# Double border-spacing with thead in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, html-table, webkit

I have a `table` that uses `thead` and `tbody`. The `table` has `border-spacing` set, and in Chrome and Safari the space between *the header row* and *the rest* is doubled.

It was reported as an [issue for Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29502) late last year, but that's the only reference to this I can find.

Has anyone else had this, or know how to get around it?

```
<table style="border-spacing: 0 5px">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It displays as expected (all rows equally spaced) in Firefox, not sure about IE.

Comment: close the <tr> inside <tbody>

Comment: This really seems to be a bug in Webkit. Do you need to include the `thead` and `tbody` tags?

Comment: @dark_charlie - it is generally said to be a lot better to specify thead and tbody - it is less markup and more meaningful if the developer has to go back to the code later, compared to specifying `<tr class='header'>bla</tr>` all the time. Also, while not using them would get around the problem, it **is** still an issue which Google needs to resolve, even if it is not a big issue.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy: Google/Apple definitely need to fix it. But before they do so, we must work it around and removing the thead and tbody tags is one of them.

Comment: @Ajtacka: You should actually create a level playing field by using reset style sheet, so you won't run into these issues often. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Could you put an actual code sample of this problem online, for instance on jsfiddle.net? I can't seem to get that bug to appear.

Answer (score 4):

thead th {position: relative; top: 5px;} will do it

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly "THE" solution, but you might want to take a look at here for a workaround which have worked with my specific case:

[How to remove extra border spacing between TBODY elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843606/)