# How to remove extra border spacing between TBODY elements?

Tags: css

**IMPORTANT: This question is no longer valid. This bug was fixed in recent versions of Chrome.**

I use `border-spacing: 1px` CSS rule to get all the cells in my `TABLE` to have a `1px` spacing between them. However, I have to use multiple `TBODY` elements in my table. I get `2px` between `THEAD`, `TBODY` and `TFOOT` elements (Chrome).

What's the easiest way to replace these `2px` gaps with `1px`?

[image: The gaps]

Exact HTML and CSS code: http://jsfiddle.net/qQA3Z/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: This is a Webkit-specific bug. (Not present in Firefox, and as usual IE won't even load jsFiddle to test it.)

Unfortunately, there is no way to *properly* fix this. There is [an open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892231/double-border-spacing-with-thead-in-chrome-and-safari) on this very topic already. Additionally, there is [an open bug report since Chrome 8](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29502) which has been confirmed to exist through Chrome 20 (and I can confirm in Chrome 25). There is also an [open Webkit bug thread](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20040) on this matter, which is still "[NEW](https://bugs.webkit.org/page.cgi?id=fields.html#status)".

To be honest, I can't even find a workaround for this. Playing with `border-spacing`, `margin`, and even `position` don't seem to have an effect on this.

Comment: The issue appears to be fixed in Canary as of today https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29502#c25

Comment: Just tested the example on an up-to-date Chrome browser, it seems to be fixed. (Also marked this as the correct answer.)

Answer (score 8):

It would appear that there's a conflict between the `border-collapse` at `table` level and the children `thead`,`tbody`,`tfoot`. A possible workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/qQA3Z/3/

```
body { margin: 10px; }
div {border: 1px solid #aaa; display:inline-block}
table {
    background: #fff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border:1px solid #fff
}

<div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td colspan='2'>Header</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Element</td><td>Element</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Element</td><td>Element</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td colspan='2'>Footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

This solves it for me:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse!important;}
```

Answer (score 4):

What personally solved it for me was changing the line-height to 0

line-height:0;
border-spacing: 0

Answer (score 1):

To remove spacing user table {border-spacing:0}